# What is the default install path for poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I installed poetry, however I'm getting the following error when attempting to call poetry

```
zsh: command not found: poetry
```

I know I have it installed because I get the following output when trying to run the following install script

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python                                                                             
Retrieving Poetry metadata                                                                                                                                                                    

Latest version already installed.
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The default install location is `~/.poetry/bin/poetry`

I added the following to my `.zshrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: when I installed it with the cURL call it didn't install it there. If I do `cd $HOME & ls -a` there is no .poetry file :'(. When I do a grep for poetry there are a ton of results at `./Library/Application Support/pypoetry`. Any idea why that is or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: i would inspect the file that is executed by the curl command, there's likely a clue as to where it was placed

Comment: The new location is `~/.local/bin/poetry`, so it should be `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: This answer is out of date, follow @PatrickYan 's update above

Comment: updated to take poetry version 1.3 into account

Comment: @Zaffer a moderator has previously rejected an edit very similar to yours, and yours has just been rejected. In the future, you may _add_ information to a post to keep it up to date, but you should not remove or edit any information in a way that conflicts with the author's original intent. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing for more information.

Answer (score 11):

Initially I wanted to run poetry within a condo environment. After running

```
pip install poetry
```

I saw it was installed using my local Python and not linked to a conda environment. In my case I added

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

to the end of the `.zshrc` file under my home directory.

Tip: You can use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> for MacOS to view your hidden files and folders :)

Answer (score 8):

Update for the new version of the [official poetry installer](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#installing-with-the-official-installer):

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

This version will install in your default `python3` bin. For example: `$HOME/Library/Python/3.9/bin`, the installer will print out the location to your shell.

Add

```
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH
```

to `~/.profile` or `~/.zprofile`.

Answer (score -1):

When I faced a situation in which other methods were not working, I just used `pip uninstall poetry` and `pip install poetry` to reinstall it and it worked