# Poetry installed but `poetry: command not found`

Tags: python, windows, python-poetry

I've had a million and one issues with Poetry recently.

I got it fully installed and working yesterday, but after a restart of my machine I'm back to having issues with it ;(

Is there anyway to have Poetry consistently recognised in my Terminal, even after reboot?

---

**System Specs:**

- Windows 10,
- Visual Studio Code,
- Bash - WSL Ubuntu CLI,
- Python 3.8.

---

**Terminal:**

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ poetry run python3 cli.py
poetry: command not found
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3
Retrieving Poetry metadata

This installer is deprecated. Poetry versions installed using this script will not be able to use 'self update' command to upgrade to 1.2.0a1 or later.
Latest version already installed.
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ poetry run python3 cli.py
poetry: command not found
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post to help further clarify.

Comment: What is your system? How did you install it? Did you use any virtualenv / conda environment during the install?

Comment: I used the `curl` command, via bash, in post. Will append system specs to post

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When I run this, after shutdown of bash Terminal:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

`poetry` command is then recognised.

However, this isn't enough alone; as every time I shutdown the terminal I need to run the `export`.

Possibly needs to be saved in a file.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I have to run it every time I want to do `poetry shell`, is there a way around that?

Comment: This answer should be updated with `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` on Unix, according to the [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/). Best is to write this in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 102):

Since this is the top StackOverflow result for "poetry command not found"...

**For Mac users**, create a `.zshrc` file in your home folder with the following:

```bash
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: You saved my life. For some reason, even after installing poetry via the recommended method, I do not have a ~/.poetry/bin directory at all. It turns out the executables are located in ~/.local/bin

Comment: This solution is working with Poetry version 1.3.2 on MacOS 13.0

Comment: You might find a .zprofile file in your home folder on newer macs (I am running a M2 pro on 13.0) which you can add this line to instead. Remember the files will be hidden and you can unhide with Command+Shift+Dot

Comment: You might want to update the terminal to reflect the changes:
restart the terminal or run the command "source ~/.zshrc"

Comment: The same worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, whereas export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH" didn't help

Comment: this answer doesn't address the question, which is for Windows 10. good info, but shouldn't be the top comment.

Comment: Still works perfectly late 2023

Answer (score 25):

I updated poetry to v1.2.2 (Nov 2022), but had issues with the path being set properly. This was the path definition I found:

**Windows 10**:
`C:\User\<myUserName>\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Scripts`

Add it temporarily to your path with:
`set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Scripts`

Or set this in your usual Windows Environment setup

Answer (score 13):

in Windows 11, after long and painful experiments with powershell and reading the poetry installation documentation, I solved the problem like this:

1. installed poetry with the command:
   `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -`

When the system reported that poetry was successfully installed and for poetry you need to register the path to the folder where it was installed. typing the `poetry --version` command there was an error in powershell that poetry is unknown, I could not register path through the command line.

2. through the windows folder window settings, I made the hidden folders and files visible and went to where poetry was installed: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts`.
3. In order for python to see the path to poetry, I copied poetry.exe from the spot `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts` in the python work environment at: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts` this way.

Pip also lies in Local. The problem was solved and the command in powershell `poetry --version` showed the poetry version. I hope this will help you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just to add - if you are not able to find the path use the command ''where python'' in your command terminal. Paste the poetry.exe in the same path

Comment: After installation via the poetry installer with the PowerShell method, I cannot navigate to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts` because it says that path doesn't exist. What is happening there?

Answer (score 12):

To follow-up on @StressedBoi69420's answer, could you add the line he suggested, i.e.
`export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"`
to your `.bashrc`?

As per this other Stack Overflow post [What is the default install path for poetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768676/what-is-the-default-install-path-for-poetry) and @arshbot's answer, I have added the line
`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin` to my `.zshrc` and it seems to be working.

Comment: In my case I didn't had a .zshrc file but adding it to ~/.zprofile worked. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 10):

After installation - To add poetry to your shell script in Mac add following commands in terminal

`open ~/.zshrc`

If zshrc file is not created previously then create it using the following commands -

The `.zshrc` file is not present by default in macOS Catalina, we need to create it.

Steps for creation:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `touch ~/.zshrc` to create the respective file. (`touch` command will create the `.zshrc` in your current directory but it will be hidden)
3. Hit Return

To open the zshrc file

1. Open Terminal > and type: `open ~/.zshrc`

   In the .zshrc file add the line -

`export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:{$PATH}”`

Once you have added the above command to the .zshrc file, go back to the terminal and refresh the terminal by -

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Then execute the following in terminal

```
poetry --version
```

If you get the version name then you are ready to use!

Additionally you can refer the https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation for further information during installation in other operating system environments.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, this solved the problem in your export command the ending " is the wrong symbol I think, I get an error when I tried to copy it directly.

Answer (score 10):

For windows (on powershell) try this please:

$Env:Path += ";C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts"; setx PATH "$Env:Path"

(from the page
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/poetry.html#c2dbb15c)

Comment: if your path is already long (more than 1024 characters) be very careful on running this command because it will truncate and only preserve the first 1024 characters from your path and can potentially leave you with a broken pc

Comment: @Theo and what would be the solution then?

Comment: one is to manually add the environment variable from the windows UI

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some beginner level context around Julien's excellent answer, to find and edit your .zshrc file, you need to use your default editor (in this case i am using VSCode) and run:

```
>> code ~/.zshrc
```

...and, crucially, restart the terminal.

More details and the source of this info here: https://superuser.com/questions/886132/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac

Answer (score 2):

MacOS:

1. curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
2. touch ~/.zshrc
3. open ~/.zshrc
4. In ~/.zshrc:
   export PATH="/Users/YOURUSERNAME/.local/bin:$PATH"
5. Save the file: cmd+S
6. Check the command:
   poetry --version

Comment: Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 2):

it helped me for Windows 10:

1. manually change PATH variable for users. add this path: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Scripts
   It's directory of poetry file. Poetry file has to be in Scripts with this path.
2. restart PC. probably path variables set after restart. in my case it helped.
3. now u can try poetry --version

Answer (score 1):

#### Generally the path of Poetry should be added to the ENV variable PATH.

#### 1. use `which` find where is poetry installed just after you installed poetry.

```
which poetry

# $HOME/.local/bin/poetry  # if installed with Brew
# maybe elsewhere: "$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

##### In fact, it reminds users to add the path to the shell configuration file in the output of the Poetry installation.

> Installing Poetry (1.2.2): Done
>
> Poetry (1.2.2) is installed now. Great!
>
> To get started you need Poetry's bin directory
> (/home/shell/.local/bin) in your `PATH` environment variable.
>
> Add `export PATH="/home/shell/.local/bin:$PATH"` to your shell
> configuration file.
>
> Alternatively, you can call Poetry explicitly with
> `/home/shell/.local/bin/poetry`.

#### 2. find what kind of shell you are using:

```
echo $SHELL

# /usr/bin/zsh    # many people use zsh or oh-my-zsh
  # For zsh, put stuff in ~/.zshrc, which is always executed.
  # For bash, put stuff in ~/.bashrc, and make ~/.bash_profile source it.
```

#### 3. add the Poetry executable path to $PATH and add it to a shell startup configuration file to init it every time you start with that shell:

```
export SHELL_RCFILE="~/.zshrc"
echo "export POETRY_PATH=$HOME/.local/bin/ && export PATH="$POETRY_PATH:$PATH" >> $SHELL_RCFILE
```

Reference: [zsh, bash startup files loading](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Answer (score 1):

After installation of Poetry you gotin output command line the tips:

- Add `export PATH="/Users/USERNAME/.local/bin:$PATH"` to your shell configuration file.
- Alternatively, you can call Poetry explicitly with `/Users/USERNAME/.local/bin/poetry`.

ps: I've installed it in MacOS using `curl`.

Comment: Life saver. Other answers didn't work for me. Thank you immensely.

Answer (score 1):

In [Windows 10 using WSL2](https://python-poetry.org/docs/), after running

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

[image]

That essentially tells to run

```
export PATH="/home/tperes/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

After, when running `poetry --version` will get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For windows you install curl with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) by running the following command:

`choco install curl`

after installation is complete run the following command to install [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-the-official-installer).

`curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -`

**OutPut**

```
Poetry (1.5.1) is installed now. Great!

To get started you need Poetry's bin directory (C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts) in your `PATH`
environment variable.

Alternatively, you can call Poetry explicitly with `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\poetry`.

You can test that everything is set up by executing:
```

`poetry --version`

Add poetry's bin directory (C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts) in your `PATH`
environment variable.

Check if poetry works `poetry --version`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh, just add your python path where the packages are installed to ~/.zprofile. For me, my pip location is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3. So execute the below.

vi ~/.zprofile

> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}

source ~/.zprofile

Answer (score 0):

There is already a file named ".bashrc" , located in your home directory, is read-in and executed whenever a bash script or bash shell is started.

open it and add bellow line to avoid redandant task:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hello so uh my Specs is:

Windows 10

so bassically go to the docs of https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation

and after that use

(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -

if you have py not python 3

then after go to environment variables

then go to your local variables then add new
then set the variable name to:

variable name: Path
variable path: %APPDATA%\Python\Scripts

after that use poetry --version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall Poetry, resolved it for me:

```
$ poetry
bash: poetry: command not found...
$ pip uninstall poetry
Found existing installation: poetry 1.7.1
Uninstalling poetry-1.7.1
...
$ pip install poetry
...
Successfully installed cachecontrol-0.14.0 poetry-1.8.2 poetry-core-1.9.0
$ poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.8.2)
```