# Poetry installed but `poetry: command not found` on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, python-poetry

I was following this [github](https://github.com/PyAntony/hate-speech), where it gave me the following instructions:

> Project was built with poetry (https://python-poetry.org/), so it is
> recommended to get poetry first to install all the dependencies. After
> poetry installation you can simply clone this repo, navigate to the
> root directory, and run:
> From the website I ran this command:

```
!curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

After executing this I get the following prompt:

```
Retrieving Poetry metadata

# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

/root/.local/bin

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing Poetry (1.1.15)
Installing Poetry (1.1.15): Creating environment
Installing Poetry (1.1.15): Installing Poetry
Installing Poetry (1.1.15): Creating script
Installing Poetry (1.1.15): Done

Poetry (1.1.15) is installed now. Great!

To get started you need Poetry's bin directory (/root/.local/bin) in your `PATH`
environment variable.

Add `export PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"` to your shell configuration file.

Alternatively, you can call Poetry explicitly with `/root/.local/bin/poetry`.

You can test that everything is set up by executing:

`poetry --version`
```

Thus, I ran the following command next:

```
!export PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

This gave no issues. But, after running `poetry --version`. It gave me the following error prompt:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-4666e7fa95ae> in <module>
----> 1 poetry --version

NameError: name 'poetry' is not defined
```

Can anyone help how to run this? I am new to colab. I got a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70003829/poetry-installed-but-poetry-command-not-found). But, it is not working in my case.

Using something like this: `!/root/.local/bin/poetry --version` is working, but how do I add that $PATH in the shell configuration file in colab, so I don't have to call it by using the path before it every time?